# Calculate polynomial in matlab with custom degree

Tags: matlab

I have an equation :

5 + 6x + 7x^1.5 + 4x^2

Can I calculate the roots of x using matlab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
syms x
eq=5 + 6*x + 7*x^(15/10) + 4*x^2;
sol=solve(eq,x);
vpa(sol,16)


- 0.3923580269955611 + 0.3897288587097241i
- 0.3923580269955611 - 0.3897288587097241i
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, using `fzero` - as long as the function has non-imaginary roots. To include imaginary roots, see the [answer by @Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297820/232610)

```
fun = @(x)5+6*x+7*x.^1.5+4*x.^2;
oneRoot = fzero(fun,0); %# find a root starting to look at zero
```

However, it is usually a good idea to plot the function before doing any kind of optimization problem (if possible), both to identify good starting values, and to see whether there might be bad surprises, such as no root, in your case.

```
figure
ezplot(fun,[-10 10])
```

[image]

You'll note that there is not data for x<0, since your function returns imaginary values for negative input arguments. Also, the function appears to be strictly positive, so you won't find any `x` for which `y==0`.

Comment: Probably you meant "your function returns *imaginary* values for negative input" .

Answer (score 3):

For a numeric solution, you have to use `fminsearch` to find an imaginary root.

```
fun = @(x)5+6*x+7*x.^1.5+4*x.^2;
%objective function: fun2 is zero for roots and never negative, searching mins of fun2 for a solution
fun2=@(x)(abs(fun(x(1)+i*x(2))));
oneRoot = sum(fminsearch(fun2,[0,0])*[1,i]);
```